# Voltage Divider producing unexpected voltage

Tags: resistors, voltage-divider, multimeter, ohms-law

I am attempting to create a voltage divider that create 4.5 volts from a 9v battery.

Using the voltage divider equation  `4.7k / (4.7k + 4.7k) ) * 9v = 4.5v`, I decided to use two 4.7k resistors.

When I tested my circuit in a simulator, the voltage produced from the voltage divider was not 4.5 volts.
(the led is just for testing purposes)

I got the same result on a real breadboard. I tested the voltage across R2 in addition to the led. Both voltages were 1.83v

[image: simulator result]

Comment: Remove the LED and re-measure.

Comment: Voltage divider is not intended to power anything. When a current drawn from it, the voltage is changing.

Comment: No, the "output" of your voltage divider is the centerpoint between the two resistors.  Measure between that point and ground and you will have roughly 4.5V.  The problem is that your LED is loading the voltage divider (and clamping the output to the Vf of the LED.)

Comment: how would you use a voltage divider as a reference if you can't put a load on it @EugeneSh.

Comment: @PatRoche You can put a very high-resistance load that will draw nearly zero current.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your math only holds true if there is NO load between the 2 resistors. Even a DVM with a 10M ohm input will cause a slight drop in the value, but if your using 5% tolerance resistors *you could* have a +/-10% error in the actual voltage.
 To get close to 4.500vdc you need an accurate 9.00vdc source, and use 1% or even .1% resistors to increase accuracy. Now you should have 4.50vdc at the test point, minus the 10M load of the DVM, which is about .05%, giving you a reading of 4.497vdc under ideal conditions.
 **Leave out the LED** as it is shorting out your divider. Your meter reading of 1.83 volts is actually the voltage the LED is clamping at to work properly. The DVM is a better test method in this case.
**NOTE:** 4.7K 10% and 5% resistors go back about 40 years or more. To get 1% or 0.1% tolerance resistors you may need to use their common values, such as 4.99K.

Comment: This downvote seems suspicious without explanation.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I would agree, as the OP was satisfied with my answer, and the math was simple. I think it was a 'hit-and-run'.

Comment: Not my dv, but maybe it's because you don't mention that the LED is shorting the lower part of the divider, and this effect is surely bigger than the effect from the meter.

Comment: "OP was satisfied" is not a good indicator for whether the answer is good, especially for OP's asking very basic questions.

Comment: @ThePhoton. Then I will define the issues with the LED more, in case the OP missed that.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your side question,

> How would you use a voltage divider as a reference if you can't put a load on it?

A voltage divider *is* a reference, and you can't put much of a load onto references directly as you found out; the reference changes. There of course is a way around this, but it requires more components:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSN5aw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here the [operational amplifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier) OA1 is wired in a non-inverting buffer configuration, meaning that whatever is fed into it's + input, appears on it's output.

Why do this? Because of two great properties of op-amps:

- Their inputs take very little current, so point A is not loaded down and stays very close to 4.5v.
- Their outputs can source and sink much more current. So point B has enough current to light the LED, without influencing point A. If you put a multi-meter on the op-amp output and ground, there should be about 4.5v.

Now the op-amp shown here is only an example, and you'd want to pick a real op-amp model depending on (many) other factors in your circuit. Op-amps are a large field, with many details to study.